# Can I dynamically get an argument name of a method (not parameter name)?

Tags: java, reflection

Here's code

```java
    public Configuration setProperty(int someSpecificProperty) {
        MyAppUtil.requirePositive(someSpecificProperty, "someSpecificProperty");
        this.someSpecificProperty = someSpecificProperty;
        return this;
    }
```

```java
// MyAppUtil
    static void requirePositive(int property, String propertyName) {
        if (property <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalPropertyException(propertyName, PropertyIssue.NON_POSITIVE);
        }
    }
```

```java
public class IllegalPropertyException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final String FORMAT = "%s value is invalid: should be %s";
    public IllegalPropertyException(String propertyName, PropertyIssue propertyIssue) {
        super(String.format(FORMAT, propertyName, propertyIssue.whatItShouldBeInstead()));
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public enum PropertyIssue {
        NULL("not null"), EMPTY("not empty"), NON_POSITIVE("greater than zero");

        private final String whatItShouldBeInstead;

        String whatItShouldBeInstead() {
            return whatItShouldBeInstead;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I pass both a property and that property's name. I am wondering whether I could get that information about the argument name dynamically so that the client (or rather, I) don't have to pass it manually each time. It would've been nice if I could call the `requrePositive()` method like this (and `MyAppUtil` figured out the argument name itself):

```java
    public Configuration setSpecificProperty(int someSpecificProperty) {
        MyAppUtil.requirePositive(someSpecificProperty);
        this.someSpecificProperty = someSpecificProperty;
        return this;
    }
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, can't do it. Variable names are for humans, not for computers.

Comment: @Kayaman Sad. I guess I could get the setter name and parse it, though... But that would make my `require*()` methods less versatile (only fit for setters)

Comment: Or just bite the bullet and pass the name. Then concentrate on more important things in software development. Also maybe import some library that already has those validations so you don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Create a class that holds both _int property_ and _String propertyName_, and pass this as the parameter.

Comment: Methods receive *values*. Nothing guarantees that the value originates from something that has a name, like a variable. Besides that, you are making your job unnecessarily hard by inventing a new terminology. If a method named `setSpecificProperty` with a single argument throws an `IllegalArgumentException`, everyone understands that the method’s single argument which was supposed to be the new value for the `Specific` property (regardless of how the parameter variable is actually named) is illegal, without the need to repeat the name “Specific” in the exception message.